# Can an EUSS Family permit be used to visit?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, eu

Can an EU Settlement Scheme Family Permit be used in place of a standard visitor visa to visit family in the UK, if you qualify for it?

- It's listed as an option for coming to the UK in the gov.uk wizard.
- The language around it suggests that it's meant as a precursor to applying for pre-settled status.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From [EU Settlement Scheme Family
Permit and Travel Permit](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/65c210e0373948000d2135ec/EU+Settlement+Scheme+Family+permits.pdf)

> The EU Settlement Scheme (EUSS) family permit is an entry clearance which facilitates travel to and entry into the UK of an eligible family member of a relevant European Economic Area (EEA) citizen or (where an application was made by 8 August 2023) of a qualifying British citizen.

> The family permit enables the holder to join in, or accompany to, the UK their relevant EEA citizen or qualifying British citizen.

> Where an EUSS family permit is issued, it will be valid for a period of **6 months from the date of decision** on the application.

> The holder can enter the UK as many times as they wish during that period.